# requirejs multiple paths one library

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Ignoring the fact that this might not be a good idea is it possible to get requirejs to reference one library using two different paths i.e

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'ko': '../Lib/knockout-2.1.0.debug',
        'knockout': '../Lib/knockout-2.1.0.debug',
    }
});
```

or possibly some other way? Currently its complaining

The reason is we have some external libraries that have external dependancies on 'knockout' where as we use 'ko'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a [map configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) is a better approach here. If you have modules that require 'ko' but others require 'knockout', then simply map 'ko' to 'knockout' for your modules.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout': '../Lib/knockout-2.1.0.debug',
    },
    map: {
        '*': { 'ko': 'knockout' }
    }
});
```

And if only certain module names need the remapping, replace "*" with module name in the above example.

Or, if by "where as we use 'ko'" you also mean window.ko, you can do this instead:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout': '../Lib/knockout-2.1.0.debug',
    }
});

define('ko', ['knockout'], function (punch)
{
  window.ko = punch;
  return punch;
});
```